# "Textbox is a type but used like variable" error

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want edit a Grid View using code behind and classes, without datasource controls. I wrote this code:

```
 private void ZaladujGridView()
{
    GridView2.DataSource = EuroPilka.terminarzLiga.wyswietlTerminarz();
    GridView2.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
    {
        int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
        GridView2.EditIndex = rowIndex;
        ZaladujGridView();
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "UpdateRow")
    {

        int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string druzyna = ((TextBox).GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;

        EuroPilka.terminarzLiga.aktualizujTerminarz(id, druzyna);
        GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
        ZaladujGridView();
    }
}
```

but in line

```
string druzyna = ((TextBox).GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

I've got error: "Textbox is a type but used like variable". Could You tell what is wrong with that ?

Comment: remove the dot after (TextBox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dot here:

`((TextBox).`

I think it should just be:

`((TextBox) GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1"))`

Because you're casting.

Comment: You are right, Thank You !. I will accept answer in 6 minutes ;)